# Adding multiple columns in temp table from dataframe using pyspark

Tags: dataframe, azure, pyspark, databricks

Trying to create a table in Pyspark in Databricks which would capture database name, table name and DDL statement for each table. Hive metastore has been loaded in AzureMySQL on which Databricks cluster is pointing. While in separate dataframe objects I am able to capture needed details, however unable to combine them into one single table. Schema I am looking at : DatabaseName, TableName, CreateDDLStatement, Location.
For database name and table name here is the dataframe df1

```
tables = spark.catalog.listTables(db)
for t in tables:
    Df1 = spark.sql("show tables in db1")
    Df1.createOrReplaceTempView("TempTable1")
    result1 = sqlContext.sql('select * from TempTable1')
    result1.show()
Output -
DatabaseName TableName IsTemporary
db1          tb1       False
db2          tb2       True db = "db1"
tables = spark.catalog.listTables(db)
for t in tables:
    Df1 = spark.sql("show tables in db1")
    Df1.createOrReplaceTempView("TempTable1")
    result1 = sqlContext.sql('select * from TempTable1')
    result1.show()
Output -
DatabaseName TableName IsTemporary
db1          tb1       False
db2          tb2       True
```

Second dataframe objects has DDL statement for each table

```
for t in tables:
    DF2 = spark.sql("SHOW CREATE TABLE {}.{}".format(db, t.name))
    DF2.createOrReplaceTempView("TempTable2")
    result2 = sqlContext.sql('select * from TempTable2')
    result2.show(10)
crtmnt_stmnt
create table tb1....
create table tb2

Expected Output
DatabaseName TableName IsTemporary   crtmnt_stmnt
db1          tb1       False         create table tb1...
db2          tb2       True          create table tb2...
```

Can I append a column to dataframe object or temporary table. how to dynamically take values using withColumn and spark.sql command

Comment: Can you please clarify this: You are creating a temporary view which has list of your tables and you want to create another temporary view where you have another column `crtmnt_stmnt` which has the value as `create table <database>.<tableName>`. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Yes right . For each table name entry, last column crtmnt_stmnt will have "create table ..." I can take values in two different dataframes, however unable to club in one single table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a Dataframe where you have database and table name (which are used while create `crtmnt_stmnt` column), you can achieve this with dataframes itself.

- The following is the dataframe I have using code similar to yours:

```
df1= spark.sql("show tables in default")
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("default.temp_table")
result = spark.sql("select * from temp_table")
result.show()
```

[image]

- Now, I have created a dataframe that has all the details required. Iterating through `tables`, I created a temporary dataframe which I am appending to my final dataframe. I have also added 2 columns while doing so i.e., `tablename and database` using `withColumn`.
- This is because we will have key columns in our final dataframe(create statement dataframe) using which we can apply inner join on the above df1.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,lit,concat
df2=None
db='default'
for t in tables:
    if(df2 is None):
        df2 = spark.sql("SHOW CREATE TABLE {}.{}".format(db, t.name))
        df2 = df2.withColumn("table_name",lit(t.name)).withColumn("db_name",lit(db))
    else:
        temp = spark.sql("SHOW CREATE TABLE {}.{}".format(db, t.name))
        temp = temp.withColumn("table_name",lit(t.name)).withColumn("db_name",lit(db))
        df2 = df2.union(temp)
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("create_table")

#display(df2)
```

[image]

- I have used pyspark to apply inner join to get the desired result.

```
final = df1.join(df2,(df1.tableName == df2.table_name) & (df1.database == df2.db_name),"inner").select(df1['database'],df1['tableName'],df1['isTemporary'],df2['createtab_stmt'])
display(final)
```

[image]

- Using `spark.sql()` the code would be as follows (using the temporary views created)

```
spark.sql("select d1.database,d1.tableName,d1.isTemporary,d2.createtab_stmt from temp_table d1 inner join create_table d2 on d1.database=d2.db_name and d1.tableName=d2.table_name").show()
```

Comment: Hi Saideep, I would need the output of below command to be appended. I see you concatenating the values as constants which s would not solve the purpose. The DDl gets dynamically created with below command ``` DF2 = spark.sql("SHOW CREATE TABLE {}.{}".format(db, t.name))```   create table tb1 ( col1 datatype1, col2 datatype2 ........).  This output from "SHOW CREATE TABLE" command needs to be appended. Please help me achieve that.